# What would happen if the Cruciatus Curse was used on a pregnant person?

Tags: harry-potter

In the Harry Potter series, what could happen if Crucio was performed on a pregnant witch? Could it affect the child or terminate the pregnancy? Or would it just affect the mother?

Comment: Since we don't see an instance of this in the films or books (nor has JKR spoken about it, to the best of my knowledge), any answer is likely to be pure conjecture.

Comment: Since the aim of the curse is to cause unrelenting pain, you might do better to ask on [Health:SE](https://health.stackexchange.com/) whether unrelated pain can cause miscarriage/premature labour or fetal death.

Comment: It's probably answerable, based on evidence in the books for the amount of pain that the Cruciatus Curse causes, the severity of the pain, and the amount of stress it causes.

Answer (score 4):

**Crucio may affect the child but won't necessarily cause termination, though it probably can.**

I'm not sure if an unborn child would be affected by a Cruciatus Curse performed on the mother. Punching the mother in the stomach probably won't cause the unborn child pain, but the Cruciatus Curse is magic, so it may be able to affect the unborn child as well. The Cruciatus Curse only causes extreme pain, so it isn't an automatic termination, the unborn child may survive it. Stress can cause miscarriages though, so if the pain the Cruciatus Curse causes enough stress it could terminate the pregnancy.

Comment: I can't believe that you never tried Cruciatus Curse on a pregnant woman, Bellatrix :P

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Who says I haven't?! ;) I just don't know what goes on inside them! :P